# Lyx :- Package babel Error: You haven't specified a language option

Tags: lyx, babel, languages

I get the following error in Lyx when I try to generate the pdf file.

```
Package babel Error: You haven't specified a language option
```

I have tried using the information in similar questions for TeX but it doesn't work in LyX. 
For example, I tried changing the Lyx preamble by including

```
\usepackage[english]{babel}
```

but I still get the same error. 
What is the right solution to this problem in LyX?

Minimal working example is the following standard text in a LyX file with class `article`.

Comment: `Document > Settings ... >  Language` and check the options  and the LaTeX source generated with each option. Unless you select `Language package: None` do not include  `\usepackage[english]{babel}` in the preamble.

Comment: For this and future posts, it is very helpful if you can post a minimal working example: https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Comment: Thanks. I made the change. Does that look good ?

Comment: @Fran I tried that but it didn't help. May be I need to look more into the LaTeX source.

Comment: On Debian Jessie I solved the issue by installing the corresponding textlive-lang-[language] package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What worked for me is unchecking the option "Automatically fill header" under Document-> Settings-> PDF properties. I guess that just helps never loading babel and running into the problems caused by it.

Answer (score 16):

I just ran into the same problem with a German document. Here is what fixed the problem without any workarounds in Ubuntu; You need to adjust this to your TeX/OS combination.

```
sudo apt install texlive-lang-german
```

Also note that the described PDF Properties workaround did not work in my case.
In general, I would always first look for ways to fix the actual problem, rather than using workarounds that strip my software of its features.

**Edit:** On Fedora this helped: `sudo dnf install texlive-babel-german`

Answer (score 2):

You have to install `texlive-lang-all` (or `texlive-lang-english`, `texlive-lang-italian`, etc.).

In the terminal:

```
sudo apt install texlive-lang-all
```

Then you have to change the preferences in LyX: `Language: automatic`.

It should work.